# I want to add an additional thing in my JSON with my PHPcode, what should I add for the last piece?

Tags: php, json

I want to adjust my json a tiny bit by adding an additional message, I want to reach, in this example, an image and all of its things inside the name that I makeup ("GetImage" in this case). I will give you an example so you can understand it easier.

This is what I want it to look like:

```
{
  "results": [{
    "GetImage":  //this is what I am missing
    {
      "ID": "File",
      "Name": "image3",
      "URL": "http://test.image.com/
    }
    }
    ]}
```

I have:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Name": "Aqua",
      "URL": "http://www.img.com/img1.jpg"
    }
  ]}
```

So I have to add a text named GetImage, so I can find that particular Image and its info but I am not sure where to put it in my current code:
This is my code:

```
<?php
$contacts = array();
$contacts[] = array("ID"=>1, "Name" => 'Aqua', "URL"=>'http://www.img.com/img1.jpg');
$contacts[] = array("ID"=>2, "Name" => 'Vit', "URL"=>'http://www.img.com/img2.jpg');
$contacts[] = array("ID"=>3, "Name" => 'Sit', "URL"=>'http://www.img.com/img3.jpg');
echo json_encode(array('results' => $contacts), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$contacts = array();
$contacts[] = array('GetImage' => array("ID"=>1, "Name" => 'Aqua', "URL"=>'http://www.img.com/img1.jpg'));
$contacts[] = array('GetImage' => array("ID"=>2, "Name" => 'Vit', "URL"=>'http://www.img.com/img2.jpg'));
$contacts[] = array('GetImage' => array("ID"=>3, "Name" => 'Sit', "URL"=>'http://www.img.com/img3.jpg'));
echo json_encode(array('results' => $contacts), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This Code Can Do The Job:

```
<?php

    $contacts = array();

    $contacts[] = array("ID"=>1, "Name" => 'Aqua', "URL"=>'http://www.img.com/img1.jpg');
    $contacts[] = array("ID"=>2, "Name" => 'Vit', "URL"=>'http://www.img.com/img2.jpg');
    $contacts[] = array("ID"=>3, "Name" => 'Sit', "URL"=>'http://www.img.com/img3.jpg');

    $results = array();
    $results["results"] = array('GetImage' => $contacts);

    echo json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    ?>
```

Comment: Giving you a thumbs up and the other guy an answer. Both solutions work. Thx